# I'm new in the android field and suffering with the problem for insertion in the android app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made simply a insertion folrm which will take the three numbers as input to store in the database (Please keep note that  i'm working with the sqlite database).
So the main thing is when i click on submit it will through an error which says no such table :-messgae_table.
And i try to find what is the problem with my code but nothing is worked out for me!!!!
PLEASE HELP ME OUT AT THIS.......

Main Activity.java page:-

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    DatabaseQueries db=new DatabaseQueries(Main2Activity.this);
                    Log.e("data",editText1.getText().toString());
                    long result=db.addMessageNumber(editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString(),editText3.getText().toString());
                    if (result>0){
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

DatabaseColumn.java:-

```
public static final String MESSAGE_TABLE = "message_table";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERONE = "message_numberone";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO = "messgae_numbertwo";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE = "message_numberthree";
```

DatabaseCreation:-

```
public class DatabaseCreation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "secure.db";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;


    private String message_table = "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE + " ( " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE + " TEXT, " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO + " TEXT, " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE + " TEXT )";

    public DatabaseCreation(Context context){

        super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(contact_table);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(message_table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

DatabaseQueries:-

```
public long addMessageNumber(String numberone, String numbertwo, String numberthree){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase2=db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE,numberone);
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO,numbertwo);
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE,numberthree);
        long result=sqLiteDatabase2.insert(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE,null,cv);
        sqLiteDatabase2.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Try changing `DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE + " ( " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE` with `DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE + "(" + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE`

Answer (score 0):

Your code, with the exception of ther line `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(contact_table);` appears to work when pieced together.

- The above line was commented out.

As such your issue is probably that you are used to **`onCreate`** running everytime the App is run. i.e. When an Activity is started. **However**, the `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s **`onCreate` method only runs once when the database is created**. Any other time (i.e. when the database exists) it does not run.

As such you issue is likely that the table is not found because it hasn't been created because you have added code to the `onCreate` (to create the table) without deleting the database.

## FIX :-

The **FIX** is to do 1 of the following :-

- Delete the App's data via Settings, or
- Uninstall the App (which deletes the App's data)

When one of the above is done rerun the App, which would probably get you past the Table not found error.

## Code used for Testing :-

**DatabaseColumn.java**

```
public class DatabaseColumn {
    public static final String MESSAGE_TABLE = "message_table";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERONE = "message_numberone";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO = "messgae_numbertwo";
    public static final String MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE = "message_numberthree";
}
```

**DatabaseCreation.java**

```
public class DatabaseCreation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "secure.db";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private String message_table =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE + " ( " +
                    DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE + " TEXT, " +
                    DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO + " TEXT, " +
                    DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE + " TEXT )";

    public DatabaseCreation(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(contact_table); //<<<<<<<< ?????????
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(message_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** the commented out line (you may not have to comment it out)

**DatabaseQueries.java**

```
public class DatabaseQueries {
    DatabaseCreation db;

    public DatabaseQueries(Context context) {
        db =  new DatabaseCreation(context);
    }

    //!!!!!!!!!! Code other than this block has been assumed
    public long addMessageNumber(String numberone, String numbertwo, String numberthree){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase2=db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERONE,numberone);
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTWO,numbertwo);
        cv.put(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_NUMBERTHREE,numberthree);
        long result=sqLiteDatabase2.insert(DatabaseColumn.MESSAGE_TABLE,null,cv);
        sqLiteDatabase2.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** see the comment

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText1,editText2,editText3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText1 = this.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        editText2 = this.findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        editText3 = this.findViewById(R.id.edittext3);

        //!!!!!!!!!! Code other than this block has been assumed
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    //!!!!!!!!!! view.getContext() used instead of Main2Activity.this (code is easier to copy elsewhere)
                    DatabaseQueries db = new DatabaseQueries(view.getContext());
                    Log.e("data", editText1.getText().toString());
                    long result = db.addMessageNumber(
                            editText1.getText().toString(),
                            editText2.getText().toString(),
                            editText3.getText().toString()
                    );
                    if (result > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("INSERTINFO","Row inserted."); //<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR TESTING
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("INSERTINFO","Row NOT inserted."); //<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR TESTING
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** MainActivity was used for testing instead of Main2Activity
- See the comments.
- Toast's were complemented with loggging.

## Testing Results

### First Run when Started :-

[image]

### Insertion

After entring T1, T2 and T3 in the three EditTexts and Clicking the CLICKME button then the log contains :-

> ```
> 2019-11-29 07:13:49.056 E/data: T1
> 2019-11-29 07:13:49.093 E/INSERTINFO: Row inserted.
> ```